# The userscript I made partially works. Any fix?

Tags: javascript, jquery, userscripts

I'm making a userscript to remove the ads off the homepage of [Kissanime](https://kissanime.ru/)

The anime site already gives you a button to hide the ads, but I just want to remove the button, but it doesn't work. Here is my code

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Kissanime Tool
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  Kissanime Tool
// @author       Joe Hill
// @match        *://kissanime.ru/
// @grant        none
// @require https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

(function() {
    'use strict';

    // The code below is an example of the working code
    $("#keyword").attr("value", "The script wrote here");
    //The code below doesn't work
    $(".divCloseBut").remove();
})();
```

I'm not really sure why this doesn't work.

Comment: Wait, you just want to remove the *button* (the button that, when clicked, removes the ads)? Or do you actually want to remove the ads?

Comment: show me your button

Comment: @CertainPerformance I will remove the ads later by using the code the button uses but for right now, just the button.

Comment: @Mateus Gonçalves, it says hide and it's a button on the website to remove the ads. It's not my button.

Comment: Do you really need to remove? When? Instead of removing it, you can also hide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The buttons are created dynamically, with:

```
function AddHideButtonToDynamic() {
  // some conditions
  $(elemDyna).after('<div class="divCloseBut" style="....')
}
window.setTimeout(AddHideButtonToDynamic, 5000);
```

and

```
function AddCloseButton(id) {
  // some conditions
  elem.after('<div class="divCloseBut" style="z-index:1000; ...')
}
```

It would be possible (though slightly annoying) to intercept these function calls - however, it would be easier to inject a `<style>` tag which gives the buttons `display: none`, which can be done *once, and only once*, on pageload, so you don't have to wait for the elements to appear:

```
document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('style')).textContent = `
.divCloseBut {
  display: none !important;
}`;
```

Comment: Done. Sorry about that

Comment: Is it easier to edit the onclick event of the "divCloseBut" child?

Comment: It would be harder, because you'd have to listen for the insertion of the element. (though, not that much harder if you use `setInterval`, which works, but is inelegant. `MutationObserver` would be better, but it requires more code)

Comment: Could redeclaring the function that checks the button work?

Comment: If you define the function yourself before their function declaration is parsed, a `SyntaxError` will result, which is ugly and will break the site. If you define the function after the site's is, the site will already have a reference to the one they created in the `setTimeout`, unfortunately

Comment: Is it possible for the on click code for the hide button to be set to automatically run when the website is loaded?

Comment: For `AddCloseButton`, figure out the ids you want to remove, then just select those elements (with `$` or `querySelector` or whatever you want) and `.remove()` them. Same sort of thing for `AddHideButtonToDynamic`, but you'll have to use the silly logic of the function to find the right element: `div[style*="width:100%;height:768px;"]` etc, select it and `.remove()` it

Comment: Since I'm trying to remove all ads from main page, I got the first two ads to remove (adsIfrme1 and adsIfrme3). But when I try for the third element, $(div[style*="width:100%;height:768px;"]).remove(), it doesn't work.

Comment: You have to follow the same (silly) logic as the `AddHideButtonToDynamic` - there may be some spaces in between.

Comment: I've tried that and it still doesn't work. What do the brackets [0] and [1] mean?

Comment: That selects either the first or second item in the collection to the left of the brackets

Comment: Worst case, just select em all: `$('div[style*="width:100%;height:768px;"], div[style*="width: 100%; height: 768px;"], div[style*="width:100%;height:768px;"], div[style*="width: 100%; height: 768px;"]').remove();`

Comment: Here is a link of my code. i'm not sure what I'm doing wrong https://snag.gy/aUgtsY.jpg

Comment: The ad elements might not be inserted instantly, it looks like they get added after a tick - run your code after a small `setTimeout`

Comment: It works, but is there a way to use setTimeout without having to make a whole new function? Here is my code https://snag.gy/XSAaiP.jpg

Comment: Not really, but you can use a function expression`setTimeout(() => { /* rest of your code */`

Comment: You got it to work. Thanks a lot. I really want to put you as a contributor because without you, I never could've gotten this script to work. Is it ok if I mention you?